# How does wmode="transparent" works?

Tags: flash, delphi, html, activex

I have an activex object  (developed in delphi 6) and floating div message. When I dragging floating div over activex object its blinking.

I'd like to add wmode param to my activex object like in flash objects to overcome this blinking, how does this feature works exactly ?

By the way I developing activex in Delphi 6 and already tried to use DoubleBuffered and VCLFixPack and there were a little improvement but it didnt fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the concept, it does not do anything by itself.

The HTML will just send all the parameters to the embedded object (be it Flash or your own custom control) so `wmode` is just another parameter.

The real work must be done on your side, HTML can't make it transparent for you, it treat the object as "black box" and can only pass it parameters.

Comment: I need to know how wmode works inside the activex or at least what command in activex will solve this blinking.

Comment: Like I said, it does't do any work. It's just a parameter passed to your object.